# How to get full file path present in eclipse project explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am working on eclipse plugin. In this i have a file name present in a project hierarchy. i need the full path of file **abc.java** present in project Test.

The file presented in path **F:/Test/src/main/java/com/sung/Pre/abc.java**

```
    IWorkspaceRoot rootWorkspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = rootWorkspace.getProject("/Test");
    file1 = project.getFile("/abc.java");

    FileEditorInput fileEditorInput = new FileEditorInput(file1);

    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IEditorDescriptor desc = workbench.getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file1.getName());
    IWorkbenchPage page11 = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    try {

        page11.openEditor(fileEditorInput, desc.getId(),true);
    } catch (PartInitException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is searching file in /Test folder. If the file presented in the root Test folder it's able to open this file but if it's inside some folder like  **F:/Test/src/main/java/com/sung/Pre/abc.java** than it's can not find the file.

I also tried below code but facing the same issue

```
    try {

        //IDE.openEditor(page11, uri, "org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE", true);
        IDE.openEditor(page11, file1, true);
    } catch (PartInitException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so my question is if we have a file name presented in project hierarchy so how can we get the absolute or full path of that.

**Please remember that i am doing this task in eclipse plugin project**

Comment: Is your filename going to be hardcoded like that? For example, if you are using a Selection object for the file and you would like the full path, then you could use IResource.getLocation() on the IResource represented by abc.java

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a path on `project.getFile`:

```
project.getFile(new Path("src/main/java/com/sung/Pre/abc.java"));
```

or get the `IFolder` for the folder containing the file and use

```
folder.getFile(new Path("abc.java"));
```

Comment: folder.getFile(new Path("abc.java")); 

It's give me a output like L/test/abc.java

Comment: You have to get the `IFolder` for the folder containing your file, perhaps using `project.getFolder(new Path("src/main/java/com/sung/Pre"))`

Comment: can u give me little bit more idea about IFolder. i got this site http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder but not able to understand this line codeCoverFolder=project.getFolder(CodeCoverPlugin.CODECOVER_FOLDER); .

Comment: There is lots of stuff in the Eclipse help, perhaps start here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm  Also in the Javadoc for the actual classes